# np.where code - ValueError: "cannot set items on DatetimeIndexResampler"

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I created a data frame to use when testing the resample features as follows:

```
f = pd.DataFrame(data=np.linspace(50, 100, 200), index=pd.date_range(end='2014-06-18', periods=200), columns=['last'])
f
Out[63]:
last
2013-12-01  50.000000
2013-12-02  50.251256
2013-12-03  50.502513
```

I then use the resample like this:

```
f_d1_resamp = f.resample('1w')
```

I then wanted to use np.where to create a new column when certain criteria are met:

```
f_d1_resamp['Gap'] = np.where(f['last'] > f['last'].shift(),(f["last"].shift() - f["last"]),'');
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot set items on DatetimeIndexResampler
```

How do I modify my np.where code to stop this error?  I need to use np.where as this will be utilised for my other projects.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add some aggragate function like `mean`, `sum`, because in version `0.18.0` was `API` changed and return `Resampler` - see [resample api](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#resample-api):

```
f_d1_resamp = f.resample('1w').sum()
```

Then you can use `numpy.where` - I think better is genarally use new `f_d1_resamp` instead `f`, because there can be down or up sampling:

```
f_d1_resamp['Gap'] = np.where(f_d1_resamp['last'] > f_d1_resamp['last'].shift(), 
                              f_d1_resamp["last"].diff(),'');
print (f_d1_resamp)
                  last                 Gap
2013-12-01   50.000000                    
2013-12-08  357.035176    307.035175879397
2013-12-15  369.346734  12.311557788944754
2013-12-22  381.658291  12.311557788944697
2013-12-29  393.969849  12.311557788944697
2014-01-05  406.281407  12.311557788944754
2014-01-12  418.592965  12.311557788944697
2014-01-19  430.904523  12.311557788944697
2014-01-26  443.216080   12.31155778894481
2014-02-02  455.527638  12.311557788944697
2014-02-09  467.839196   12.31155778894464
...
...
...
```

Comment: Yes, you can accept only one answer, but you can upvote both.

Answer (score 1):

First issue is that your resample object is just a resampler, you need to call some aggregate function like `mean`, secondly even if that were to be fixed your line:

```
f_d1_resamp['Gap'] = np.where(f['last'] > f['last'].shift(),(f["last"].shift() - f["last"]),'')
```

raises `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

for this you can use `where` directly on the desired result rather than use `np.where`:

```
In [305]:
f_d1_resamp = f.resample('1w').mean()
f_d1_resamp['Gap'] = f['last'].diff().where(f['last'] > f['last'].shift(),'')
f_d1_resamp

Out[305]:
                 last       Gap
2013-12-01  50.000000          
2013-12-08  51.005025  0.251256
2013-12-15  52.763819  0.251256
2013-12-22  54.522613  0.251256
2013-12-29  56.281407  0.251256
2014-01-05  58.040201  0.251256
2014-01-12  59.798995  0.251256
2014-01-19  61.557789  0.251256
2014-01-26  63.316583  0.251256
2014-02-02  65.075377  0.251256
2014-02-09  66.834171  0.251256
2014-02-16  68.592965  0.251256
2014-02-23  70.351759  0.251256
2014-03-02  72.110553  0.251256
2014-03-09  73.869347  0.251256
2014-03-16  75.628141  0.251256
2014-03-23  77.386935  0.251256
2014-03-30  79.145729  0.251256
2014-04-06  80.904523  0.251256
2014-04-13  82.663317  0.251256
2014-04-20  84.422111  0.251256
2014-04-27  86.180905  0.251256
2014-05-04  87.939698  0.251256
2014-05-11  89.698492  0.251256
2014-05-18  91.457286  0.251256
2014-05-25  93.216080  0.251256
2014-06-01  94.974874  0.251256
2014-06-08  96.733668  0.251256
2014-06-15  98.492462  0.251256
2014-06-22  99.748744       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to also mark this as answered but can I only select one answer?